# Does Spring Data Redis support Java streams?

Tags: java, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I can't find it explicitly in https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/ but I was wondering if Redis supports Java streams so we can do

```
Stream<SomeDataStruct> findByServerIdAndSiteIdAndUserId(String serverId, String siteId, int userId);
```

And it will free up the resources as needed?

I know JPA does support streams, though I had to explicitly do a `entityManager.detach(element)` in order to prevent the entity manager taking up a lot of memory.

I was thinking it would be in their spring-data-commons but https://spring.io/projects/spring-data#learn do not have any links just labels.

Comment: Did you try declaring that method? What happened?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to get to the point of my code to verify this

Adding

```
Stream<ArtifactOnKafka> streamByServerIdAndSiteId(String serverId, String siteId);
```

And accessing it gives

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class cc.ArtifactOnKafka cannot be cast to class java.util.stream.Stream (cc.ArtifactOnKafka is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @2cfb4a64; java.util.stream.Stream is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

So it appears it is not supported.

To fake it

```
    default Stream<ArtifactOnKafka> streamByServerIdAndSiteId(String serverId, String siteId) {
        return findByServerIdAndSiteId(serverId, siteId).stream();
    }
```